# How do I create a DOM node with text which contains HTML tags within it

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In the following code, the `CreateTextNode` function does not use the HTML tags contained in the `text` variable. Instead, it displays the raw HTML text in the result.

```
var i,text;
for(i=0;i<p.length;i++){
    text+=p[i].name+"<br>"+p[i].id+"<br>"+p[i].image;   
    //text contain embedded HTML tag.   

}

var para=document.createElement("p");
var node=document.createTextNode(text);

para.appendChild(node);
var element=document.getElementById("one");
element.appendChild(para);
```

Comment: Recommended reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the text treated as HTML and parsed, use the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property, not a text node:

```
var para=document.createElement("p");
para.innerHTML = text;
```

Alternately, you could use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```
var para=document.createElement("p");
para.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", text);
```

...but setting `innerHTML` is probably simpler in this case, since you just created the element and you know it's empty.